# PHP getElementById not working

Tags: php, domdocument

So I'm trying to write a short function using PHP to check whether a server (or the back up) is available. The service provides two servers to use, and a page within the server that simply has "OK" in an element with id "server_status". I basically took their code that they provided and adjusted it so that it provides the kind of output I need. I want to get an array of true or false (depending on whether one of the sites is available), and the correct page if it is. Right now the output every time is (false, "e404.html"), which is what I set it up to output if no conditions are met. Here is my code:

```
function checkURL() {
        $servers = array('tpeweb.paybox.com', // primary URL
        'tpeweb1.paybox.com'); // backup URL
        foreach($servers as $server){
            $doc = new DOMDocument();
            $doc->loadHTMLFile('https://'.$server.'/load.html');
            $server_status = "";
            $element = $doc->getElementById('server_status');

            if($element){
            $server_status = $element->textContent;
            }
            if($server_status == "OK"){
            // Server is up and services are available
            return array(true, 'https://'.$server.'/cgi/MYchoix_pagepaiement.cgi');
            }
        }
        return array(false, 'e404.html');
    }
```

Doing some output testing, it appears that I'm loading the document into $doc, but it doesn't fill $element. I'm new to PHP so I'm not quite sure what is wrong.

EDIT:

This is the original code that the service provided to make this check, I adjusted it because I needed to be able to actually output the link to use:

```
<?php
    $servers = array('urlserver.paybox.com', // primary URL
    'urlserver1.paybox.com'); // backup URL
    $serverOK = "";
    foreach($servers as $server){
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadHTMLFile('https://'.$server.'/load.html');
        $server_status = "";
        $element = $doc->getElementById('server_status');
        if($element){
            $server_status = $element->textContent;
        }
        if($server_status == "OK"){
            // Server is up and services are available
            $serverOK = $server;
            break;
        }
        // else : Server is up but services are not available .
    }
    if(!$serverOK){
    die("Error : no server found");
}
?>
//echo 'Connecting to https://'.$server.'/cgi/MYchoix_pagepaiement.cgi';
```

Thanks,
Adrian

Comment: whats your server status variable contents?

Comment: It is working for me.. PHP 5.4

Comment: Works well here, code seems to be OK. Guessing for something in PHP conf.

Comment: The dom part works (https://eval.in/302057) check that you can fetch the HTML.

Comment: I'll look into whether I can change the PHP configuration, thanks.

Comment: I'm using PHP 5.3.6, it looks like everything that I need is enabled...

Comment: As said in Heinrich’s answer, you can not use `getElementById` here. Use an XPath expression that selects an element based on the value of its `id` attribute instead.

Comment: I don't really understand, does that mean I have to somehow change the doctype of the webpage I'm trying to call? When I tried what Heinrich suggested (with file_get_contents) the file contents didn't even load into my variable.

Answer (score 0):

Does your html file have a doctype declared?

from http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php

> For this function to work, you will need either to set some ID attributes with DOMElement::setIdAttribute or a DTD which defines an attribute to be of type ID.

It should be sufficient to include `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the very top of your html files, and set 
`$doc->validateOnParse = true;` before calling the getElementByID function.

Comment: I have doctype declared in the html file containing the php, but I don't control the two files that I'm loading.

Comment: can you try getting the contents of the html file first [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) , then prepend the doctype to that and use the resulting string as input for your DOMDocument using [loadHTML](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) instead of loadHTMLFile

Comment: The files provided already have the doctype, but when I try to load the file contents it doesn't load anything into the variable

Comment: No, `<!DOCTYPE html>` won’t work – HTML5 isn’t even DTD-based.